# Can't remove server connection from locations sidebar in Nautilus

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

How can I remove a server connection from the locations sidebar in Nautilus?

[image]

Comment: What you are pointing to is not a bookmark but a server connection. Can't tell you how to remove them from the list though as I never had one set up.

Comment: its a old DAV Link ... to my nextcloud...